# Is user_id in FaceBook permanent over time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is user_id (UID) in FaceBook permanent over time. Is there a garantee it will not change? It seems to be true, but I checked facebook documentation but I could not find anything.

Regerds,
Georgi

Comment: Yes of course it is. Everything else would be stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the User ID in Facebook is permanent and it will not change over time.

Fun fact : facebook.com/4 is Mark Zuckerberg's ID.